# Why does UIIndicator not move away?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, uiactivityindicatorview

I use UIActivityIndicator in my app. I have written code for it as follows:

```
-(void)startSpinner {
    
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.hidden = NO;
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(137, 160, 50, 50);
    [spinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
}
```

I call this method on the UIButton's action event, and to remove indicator I write the code as follows:

```
-(void)stopSpinner {
    
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [spinner removeFromSuperview];
    [spinner release];
}
```

on click on the button indicator appears but when I call -(void)stopSpinner method in view
willAppear the indicator does not disapppear.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self stopSpinner];
   
}
```

Even I debug the code and I found that control also goes to the `stopSpinner()`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Try making the UIIndicator in Interface Builder and see if you get the same situation.

Comment: Check the address of spinner when you start it and when you stop it.  I have a feeling that when you stop it, the `spinner` variable in your `stopSpinner` method is null.

Comment: try adding some delay for stoping Spinner

Comment: Why are you stopping a spinner in viewWillAppear?

Comment: Are all these methods in the same instance of the same class? Can you give use some idea of the order of operations here - I can't picture how you would be starting a spinner and then wanting to stop it in the same viewcontroller's viewwillappear method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have potential leak in `startSpinner` because you always create `UIActivityIndicatorView` without releasing it. Change your method like this:

```
-(void)startSpinner {
    if (spinner){
        [spinner removeFromSuperview];
        [spinner release]; spinner = nil;
    }
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(137, 160, 50, 50);
    [spinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
}
```

For stopping animation assign `stopSpinner` for another UIButton action. Cos `viewWillAppear` will fired early then you tap on any button.
ps. maybe you mean `viewWillDisappear`?